# I can not streaming trade from Horizon Server

Tags: horizon, trade

I have setup one instance running Store core and Horizon (with ingest=true). This is Core node.
One instance running Horizon server (with ingest=false). This is Horizon node.

I can run streaming payment from Horizon node. But when I streaming trade, server returns error "got bad HTTP status code 406 at cursor now". Looks like Horizon node does not accept req.Header.Set("Accept", "text/event-stream").

Did anyone encounter this issue? My Horizon version is 1.12 and Stellar core is v12.4.0rc1. Thanks.